# Copy of the certificate that the Azure Marketplace wizard generates?

Tags: azure, xconnect, azure-marketplace

I have used the Azure Marketplace to create a new deployment of Sitecore Experience Cloud (XP). During the wizard I selected `Autogenerate self-signed certificate`.

Can I download the certificate after the deployment? 
How can I get the certificate?

> Question based on:
>   https://twitter.com/nlleach/status/1012721671105589249

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No, you cannot download the certificate after the deployment.**

On the Summary page of the wizard you can read in red:

> **Important Notice:** This certificate will not be available for download
>   at any other time during or after the deployment. Please download now
>   if a copy is required.

[image: Sitecore Experience Cloud Azure Marketplace Wizard Summary]

**So you can only download the certificate on the Summary page.**